# Extract data from CURL using regex in C Programing

Tags: c, regex, curl

I am trying to extract data from CURL output by using regex. I can parse the HTML source of a webpage and save it in a text file. But, before saving it, I want to remove all the `<script>` tag from the output. This is the program :- (bbb.txt is the output text file)

```
int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "google.com";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "bbb.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Developer/1.0");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question...?

Comment: Where is the part where you parse the HTML content? If you can parse the HTML you can also parse some non-HTML stuff before writing to file.